# accessing and playing video from server in iphone app

Tags: iphone, video, streaming

I've tried researching some of the other questions and answers, but not found anything specific to my question.

I'm playing video files from a web server into an application - standard procedure. However, the application acknowledges that the file path is accessible, but it won't play the file? I've tried .mov, .m4v (h.264), etc. to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? thanks

Comment: How are you trying to play them?  There's the AVxxx controls for the player, or just open the web site with the movie on it in a UIWebView and it will play as normal.

Comment: Hi we're doing it Through the AVxxx controls within the app

Comment: if we access it via the UIwebview it plays fine, just not embedded within the app itself